# PHP OOP declaring a variable to an upper class

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

First of all, I want to write two class.

```
<?php

class A
{
    function load($v)
    {
        $this->$v = "stack";
    }
}

class Base
{
    var $lib = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->lib = new A();
    }
}


$bs = new Base();
$bs->lib->load("libx");

// Current calling method
$bs->lib->libx;




// But I want this
$bs->libx;

?>
```

I write a MVC fremawork. 
CodeIgniter can do this but I could not.
My english is poor. Because of this, don't talk me complicated please.

Comment: class Base should extend class A maybe ?

Comment: No I need to not use extend for this. Because there are a lot of class like this.

Comment: I think then you are better off using a shortcut method as mentioned in an answer here (which has been deleted it seems)

Comment: unfortunately i must call like this because; when I write html in View method, I can't call "$bs->lib->xx". because there is no "lib" variable in view. So I don't want to break my code and I want to do this like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a magic `__get` method to Base to look for the property in `lib`, and return it if it exists:

```
class A
{
    function load($v)
    {
        $this->$v = "stack";
    }
}

class Base
{
    var $lib = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->lib = new A();
    }

    public function __get($v)
    {
        if (property_exists($this->lib, $v)) {
            return $this->lib->$v;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$bs = new Base();
$bs->lib->load("libx");

echo $bs->lib->libx, PHP_EOL;
echo $bs->libx, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
stack
stack
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to this :)